# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'and'), using an observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, karma-jasmine

I have a simple profilecomponent that gets an Object containing user data from a service

```
 public profiles$: Observable<IPerson>;

  constructor(private router: Router, private userService: UserService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.profiles$ = this.userService.getUser();
    console.log(this.profiles$);
  }
```

Now i want to write a karma test that verifies data is coming in, but it keeps throwing an error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'and')

```
  beforeEach(async () => {
    const UserServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj(['getUser']);
    UserServiceSpy.getUser().and.returnValue();
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ProfileComponent],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: UserService,
          useValue: UserServiceSpy,
        },
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ProfileComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

As i understand it, the error is produced here:
UserServiceSpy.getUser().and.returnValue();

But i dont get why, as the return value of getUser is an observable alread. There is no need to use of()

```
 getUser(): Observable<IPerson> {
    let data: any = localStorage.getItem(this.storageID);
    return of(JSON.parse(data));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're creating your spy incorrectly:

> const UserServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('UserService',
> ['getUser']);

The createSpyObj function receives as a first parameter the name of the object, and the second parameter is an array of methods you want to spy on